# Magnitude of tension in a bent string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acoustics, oscillators, string

I understand tension in a straight string as a reaction force to a weight, which acts along the string, ultimately resulting from the attractive forces between the constituent particles of the string. I'm not sure how to understand tension in a curved string, such as a vibrating guitar string. I understand that an ideally elastic string is meant to have tension acting at tangent to the string, but that's about it. Is the magnitude of the tension vector equal throughout the string?

I've been going through various derivations of the wave equation for transverse motion of a string fixed at both ends and they all use the assumption that the tensions at each end of an infinitesimal segment of the string are equal in magnitude. I don't understand how this assumption is warranted.

The formula speed of wave propagation in a string involves this tension $T$ in which it is a constant. Can tension in a string be constant when it's oscillating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a small segment segment under tension

[image: pic]

From the balance of the horizontal axis you have

$$ -T \cos \theta + (T+{\rm d}T) \cos (\theta+{\rm d}\theta) = 0$$

$$ {\rm d}T \approx T \tan(\theta) {\rm d} \theta $$

Integrating by separation of variables

$$\int \frac{1}{T}\,{\rm d}T = \int \tan(\theta)\,{\rm d}\theta + K$$
$$ T = \frac{{\rm e}^K}{\cos \theta} $$

So the tension varies by the slope. High slopes makes the tension higher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could I ask though what approximation are you using to get to the line $dT\approx Ttan(\theta)d\theta$?

Comment: But if indeed the tension at different points along a curved string changes, how can this be reconcilable with derivations of the wave equation for strings in which there is no longitudinal motion, so that the horizontal components of tension are equal, as in [link](http://math.seu.edu.cn/CourseFiles/20120505213457334.pdf)? In this derivation they say that the horizontal component of tension must be constant throughout the string. But I don't see how the authors could make that inference without $T_1, T_2$ being constants themselves.

Comment: 1st order taylor series on ${\rm d}\theta$ can get you $$\cos \theta {\rm d}T  - (T+{\rm d}T) \sin \theta {\rm d}\theta =0$$ and ignore any ${\rm d}\theta {\rm d}T$ terms.

Comment: Small angle approximation yields the tensions to be constants as ${\rm d}T \approx 0$, or since $\cos \theta \approx 1$ then $$T = {\rm e}^{K}$$

Comment: Come to think of it, I think the above is wrong. I know the catenary solution of a hanging cable is $$T = H \cosh \left( \frac{x}{2 a} \right)$$ where $H$ is the minimum tension (at the low point of the cable), $a=\frac{H}{w}$ is the catenary constant and $w$ is the unit weight of the cable (in force/length units). This implies that $$T = H \sqrt{1+\theta^2}$$

Comment: Ah ok, well your answer has been helpful regardless. Could you clarify what you mean by taylor series on $d\theta$? I've always understood a taylor series as approximating a function around a point (that said, it's been a while since I dabbled in any mathematics!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31476/discussion-between-lammey-and-ja72).

Comment: What I mean is that I leave the expression with only ${\rm d}\theta$ and ${\rm d}T$ terms and get rid of any higher order terms. For example, the Taylor expansion of $\frac{T}{T+{\rm d}T} = 1- \frac{{\rm d}T}{T}$

Comment: Yeah I managed to figure it out in the end, thanks though

Comment: Shouldn't the lower angle be $θ-dθ$ since the element exerting the tension $T$ on the element under  consideration is at an angle $dθ$ below it?

Comment: $\theta - {\rm d}\theta = \theta$

Answer (score 0):

No, certainly not. In linear model there is something like static tension $T_0$ and time dependent tension $T'$.

When there is for example a standing wave on a string with fixed ends, there is a minimum of string displacement (zero) but maximum of string tension $T'$ at the fixed ends. (As an effective value throught the time.)